# JS element id is undefind

Tags: javascript, firebase, dom

I'm trying to set and get the ID of an element from Firebase but when I inspect it, it shows that the ID is undefined and I can't delete the element or edit it.

..........................................................................................................................................................................................................

my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Books</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./mystyles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="loadBooks">LOAD ALL BOOKS</button>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Isbn</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Harry Poter</td>
                <td>J. K. Rowling</td>
                <td>0-7475-3269-9</td>
                <td>
                    <button>Edit</button>
                    <button>Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Game of Thrones</td>
                <td>George R. R. Martin</td>
                <td>9780553386790</td>
                <td>
                    <button>Edit</button>
                    <button>Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <form>
        <h3>FORM</h3>
        <label>TITLE</label>
        <input type="title" id="title" placeholder="Title...">
        <label>AUTHOR</label>
        <input type="title" id="author" placeholder="Author...">
        <label>ISBN</label>
        <input type="title" id="isbn" placeholder="Isnb...">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script type="module" src="./myapp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my App.js:

```
import * as data from './mydata.js';
import createElement from './mydom.js';

window.addEventListener('load',() => {
    const elements = {
        submitButton() {return document.querySelector('form > button')},
        titleElement() {return document.querySelector('#title')},
        authorElement() {return document.querySelector('#author')},
        isbnElement() {return document.querySelector('#isbn')},
        tableBody() {return document.querySelector('table > tbody')}
    };

    elements.submitButton().addEventListener('click', onSubmitButtonClick);

    async function onSubmitButtonClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const title = elements.titleElement().value;
        const author = elements.authorElement().value;
        const isbn = elements.isbnElement().value;

        if (!title || !author || !isbn) {
            alert('Please fill all fields.');
            return;
        }

        const book = {title, author, isbn};

        try {
            const books = await data.getBooks()
            await data.createBook(book)
            createBookInTable(books)
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error)
        }
    }

    function createBookInTable(books) {
        const title = elements.titleElement().value;
        const author = elements.authorElement().value;
        const isbn = elements.isbnElement().value

        const editButton = createElement('button', 'Edit');
        editButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert('Edited')
        });

        const deleteButton = createElement('button', 'Delete');
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', deleteBook);

        const newBook = createElement('tr', [
            createElement('td', title),
            createElement('td', author),
            createElement('td', isbn),
            createElement('td', [
                editButton,
                deleteButton
            ])
        ])

        newBook.setAttribute('data-id', books.id);

        elements.tableBody().appendChild(newBook);
    }

    function getCurrentBookId(e) {
        const currTr = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        const bookId = currTr.getAttribute('data-id');
        return bookId;
    }

    async function deleteBook() {
        const bookId = getCurrentBookId(e);

        try{
            await data.deleteBook(bookId)
            newBook.remove();
        } catch(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    }

})
```

my data.js:

```
function host(endpoint) {
    return `https://softuniremotedb-66064.firebaseio.com/${endpoint}.json`;
}

const api = {
    books: 'books',
    createBook: 'books/',
    deleteBook: 'books/' 
}

export async function getBooks() {
    const response = await fetch(host(api.books));
    const books = await response.json();

    return books;
}

export async function createBook(book) {
    const createdBook = await fetch(host(api.books), {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(book)
    });

    return createdBook;
}

export async function editBook(id, book) {
    const response = await fetch(host(`${api.editBook + id}`), {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(book)
    });

    const editedBook = await response.json();

    return editedBook;
}

export async function deleteBook(id) {
    return await fetch(host(`/${api.deleteBook + id}`), {
        method: 'DELETE'
    });
}
```

my dom.js:

```
export default function createElement(type, content, attributes) {
    const result = document.createElement(type);

    if (attributes !== undefined) {
        Object.assign(result, attributes);
    }

    if (Array.isArray(content)) {
        content.forEach(append);
    } else if(content !== null || content !== undefined){
        append(content);
    }

    function append(node) {
        if (typeof node === 'string' || typeof node === 'number') {
            node = document.createTextNode(node);
        }

        result.appendChild(node);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to get/set that id?

Comment: In app.js but I'm not sure how exactly to do it

Comment: What error is shown in the console? I've tested it with your html code and if data-id is set for a `<tr>` element (e.g. the Game of Thrones book), a click on the delete button and ultimately executing `e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id')` returns the data-id just fine.

Comment: I try to inspect the new element when I create it and it shows that - <tr data-id="undefined">

Comment: How can I set id to new <tr> element and then access it so I can delete or edit the element from the table and database

Comment: I can't find a real error in your code so is suspect data-id is undefined because books.id is undefined in this line: `newBook.setAttribute('data-id', books.id);` can you add a `console.log(books.id);` before this line?

Comment: Yes it says that books is not defined

Comment: I'm really confused already... how can I fix it ?

Comment: Pheeew most likely the `getBooks()` function doesn't return an object containing an id. Try adding a `console.log(books);` before and examine that object.

Comment: It says that books is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error is inside this block:

```
try {
    const books = await data.getBooks()
    await data.createBook(book)
    createBookInTable(books)
} catch (error) {
    alert(error)
}
```

Probably you want to assign the result of the `createBook()` function to a variable - as it returns a **createdBook**. This isn't assigned nor used anywhere.

Try modifying it like this:

```
try {
    const books = await data.getBooks();
    var tempBook = await data.createBook(book);
    createBookInTable(tempBook);
} catch (error) {
    alert(error)
}
```

This will take care of the undefined id. The problem with the deletion is a different story.
Let's take a look at your code:

```
async function deleteBook() {
    const bookId = getCurrentBookId(e);

    try{
        await data.deleteBook(bookId)
        newBook.remove();
    } catch(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

Here you're trying to obtain the bookId by calling the `getCurrentBookId` function with the `e` parameter - which is undefined. `deleteBook()` is the callback function for the click listener that has the e parameter so you need to add it there.

Furthermore `newBook` is a variable outside of the scope of the deleteBook function. It's defined and within the scope of the `createBookInTable` function so you can't access it. What you need to do is get the parent `<tr>` element from the delete button once more.

```
async function deleteBook(e) {
    const bookId = getCurrentBookId(e);

    try{
        await data.deleteBook(bookId);
        var tempBook=e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        tempBook.remove();
    } catch(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry - I just realized that you're actually using the `book` variable. I modified the code above.

Comment: Okay it create new element but I can't delete it from the table and database

Comment: Okay it delete it from the table but not in the database

Comment: I'm afraid this all is beyound the scope of your initial question which I think I've answered correctly. Please consider opening a new question.